# How to do an array of matrix pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix

I want to create an array of matrix pointers.

```
int matrix1[4][1] = {
    {1} , 
    {2} ,
    {3} ,
    {4}
};

int matrix2[2][2] = {
    {1, 2} , 
    {3, 4}
};
```

I'm trying to figure out how to create an array of pointers to call those matrices.

matrix[0][0][0] should return 1 and matrix[1][1][1] should return 4.

So far I've tried this method but I'm getting segmentation fault error.

```
int *** matrix = (int ***)malloc(2 * sizeof(int **));
matrix[0] = &matrix1;
matrix[1] = &matrix2;
```

Comment: the two matrices must have the same sizes

Comment: How are you even able to assign these matrices? Do you have warnings enabled? Use something like `typedef struct { int * data; int num_rows; int num_cols; } Matrix;`, and define functions which create matrices and operate on their elements. To understand why this cannot work, think about what the compiler must do when you write `matrix[0][2][1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume 2D arrays first:

```
int x[2][2];
```

Type of `x[0]` now is ***not*** `int*`, it is int[2]. Similarly, `&x[0]` is not of type `int**`, but `int(*)[2]`. You might not have seen that before, it is a pointer to an array of two elements.

If now `x` decays to a pointer, it decays to exactly the same pointer type (`int(*)[2]`).

Unfortunatly, pointers to arrays of different size are not compatible (`int(*)[10]` is unrelated to `int(*)[12]` – apart from sharing same underlying type). So you won't be able to place them into the same array, unless you use a void* pointer. But you'd lose *any* information about array sizes, so most likely, it is not the way to go.

I personally would recommend a struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t rows;
    size_t columns;
    int*   data;
} matrix;
```

Combined with some helpers:

```
int get(matrix* m, int r, int c)
{
    return m->data[m->columns * r + c];
}

// perhaps yet setter, constructing and destructing functions?
```

Structs of this kind you could place into arrays easily...